# ignore authentication for a single page

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, authentication, web-config

i am in a very tricky situation..

I have a page that is a part of my project and i want to access it without logging in or doing anything..

Explanation:
I have a test project which has a login page, default page, Admin folder, Guest folder, and a showmessage page.

the Admin folder has pages that are accessible to only admins

the Guest folder has pages that are accessible to all users.

now when ever i type in http://localhost/Default.aspx or any other page it first takes me to the login page and only after i enter the login credentials i go to the default page and from there to the other pages.

this system works fine for me and i dont wish to change it,

but there is this page similar to default called showmessage.aspx page.

what i want is when i type http://localhost/showmessage.aspx it should ignore all the login pages and take me directly to this page.. is there a way to do that.

i have this in my webconfig:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" name="GUI" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="30" path="/">
        </forms>
    </authentication>

<location path="Admin" allowOverride="true">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrators" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Please can some1 help me.
appreciate all the help i can get. thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to specify the path directly to the page and allow everyone.

```
<location path="ShowMessage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: hahah.. yea i figured it out too.. cant believe the answer was right in front of me.. and i was making stupid code changes.. thanks a lot though.. :)